# Why is systemd-hostnamed.service started at boot and by what?

Tags: systemd, dhcpcd

`systemd-hostnamed.service` on my Bullseye is started at boot time by what?

- It does not start at boot time on my Buster.
- It generates problem when no DHCP-server is present on the network. - In that case it takes very long time before it is completed.
- I have a `CODESYScontrol` which does not set up its webserver before `systemd-hostnamed.service` is completed.

Comment: Do not post a new question. Edit details into your original question. You haven't explained what you did x in particular why conman appears to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your problem maybe it has nothing to do with `systemd-hostnamed.service` which is run at startup on both Buster & Bullseye unless you run something which is attempting to set a transient hostname. A normal *Raspberry Pi OS* does not invoke it.

Try `man systemd-hostnamed.service`